# Docker nginx ports are not available

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to use nginx on docker for windows using

```
docker container run --publish 80:80 nginx
```

it is getting the error like below:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

can anyone give me the solution......

Comment: `Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80:` kill the process that already running on this port or expose different one `docker container run --publish 81:80 nginx` then localhost:81

Comment: @Adiii: Can you turn your comment into an answer so Nick can mark it as the right answer?

Comment: @Ludo21South sure. just added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see the error is clear `Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80:` because the port is occupied. you have two option

- Kill the process the occupied the port and then run the container
- Publish different port then `80` for the Nginx contianer

```
 container run --publish 81:80 nginx then localhost:81
```

Now open http://localhost:81 should work.